# How do I combine =MONTH with another formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not very well versed when it comes to excel so apologies if this is an easy answer. I have a spreadsheet with a list of orders that have either shipped or not shipped yet, and in Column N, it lists the ship date (if the order hasn't shipped yet, the cell is blank). What I need is to take the month from Column N and convert it to a text value (i.e. 12/15/2023= Dec, 1/6/2024= Jan, etc).

What I've done so far is add another column (AD), which pulls just the month from Column N using =MONTH(N13), so if an order shipped on 12/15/2023, this formula brings back "12". Then, I have another column next to it (AE) which converts that number into a text value (if Column AD says "12," then Column AE brings back "Dec"). I've been running into an error though-- for any orders that have not shipped yet (in other words, Column N is blank), for some reason, the =MONTH function is taking that blank cell and computes it as "1", so then Column AE tells me it shipped in Jan, even though it hasn't shipped yet. I'm trying to find a formula that essentially says if Column N is blank, have it return " " as the value, otherwise, if Column N is not blank and has a date in it, have it return the number of the month using =MONTH. I know that =IF(N27=" ",AD27," ") returns a blank value, but how do I combine that formula with the =MONTH formula? Sorry if I'm not explaining this well. If possible, please explain this like I'm dumb or just tell me exactly what formula I need to be using. thanks :) [image of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTaW4.png)

EDIT: thanks you guys, you were so quick and concise. I hope all of you have an amazing day, i hope your pillow is always cold on both sides, that your charger works at any angle, that you never stub your toe again for the rest of your life, that you find a $20 bill on the floor today, and that you eat your favorite flavor of cookie today. <3

Comment: `=TEXT(N13,"Mmm")`. No need to use `MONTH` at all.

Comment: Hi! I tried this, but for the cells that are blank (orders that haven't shipped yet), it is saying "Jan." I guess if use that formula on a blank cell it automatically computes as Jan?

Comment: `=IF(N13="","",TEXT(N13,"Mmm"))`

Answer (score 3):

No need for `MONTH`. Use `TEXT` to format the date:

```
=TEXT(N13,"Mmm")
```

If you need to ignore blanks:

```
=IF(N13="","",TEXT(N13,"Mmm"))
```